# SQL Server performance fast only when refresh the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I can run a stored procedure multiple times and it wont hit it's cache: (1665ms is duration column)

[image: enter image here]

But if I then alter the stored procedure changing nothing: (240ms is duration column)

[image]

Problem: how to get the stored procedure to always be fast (on the second and next calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some digging I found that when I called the SP initially (after a reboot) with a NULL applicationID

```
exec [dbo].[usp_Tab32] @responsibleReviewerID=1135,@applicationID=NULL,@environment=1,@userUIStatus=0,@roleID=NULL
```

then with a more confined query:

exec [dbo].[usp_Tab32] @responsibleReviewerID=1135,@applicationID=1406,@environment=1,@userUIStatus=0,@roleID=NULL

This would be slow.

However if I hit the more confined query first, then both would be fast.

To clear down the database plan cache:

```
DECLARE @dbId INTEGER
SELECT @dbId  = dbid FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = ‘myDatabase’
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (@dbId)
```

More detail [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543164/QueryplusOptimizationplusandplustheplusSQLplusServ)

All against SQL2012 Developer edition.

Comment: Worth having a look at this: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html Especially the OPTIMIZE FOR hints. Clearing down the whole plan cache isn't ideal, so if you can use the hints instead it'll help you out on busier systems.

Comment: Thanks Meff - yes agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Create your stored procedure with RECOMPILE and recompile at Runtime

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourprodecurename
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    --your code here
GO
```

then call it in this way:

```
EXEC yourprodecurename WITH RECOMPILE
```

This should give you the experience you want, because, when a procedure is compiled for the first time or recompiled, the procedures query plan is optimized for the current state of the database.

So this can improve the procedure’s processing performance.

Comment: Many thanks yeradis.  In my case I found this degraded the performance.